# Configurar PHPMailer para Newsletter

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer, plugin-wordpress

Estou utilizando o WordPress e nele, o plugin SendPress para o envio da Newsletter. A configuração é feita a partir do arquivo PHPMailer.

O problema é que ele está enviando apenas para os emails que estão dentro do meu domínio. Quando mando para um email externo (gmail, outlook, yahoo e etc) o mesmo não funciona.

Pelo que entendo, o único trecho de código onde tenho que modificar é o que segue abaixo:

Adiciono o emai de envio, o "sender", host -> mail.meudominio.com.br``e a porta que é `587`.

Onde estou errando? Existe outro trecho e ou arquivo que devo modificar??

```
class SendPress_PHPMailer
{
/**
 * The PHPMailer Version number.
 * @type string
 */
public $Version = '5.2.10';

/**
 * Email priority.
 * Options: 1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low.
 * @type integer
 */
public $Priority = 3;

/**
 * The character set of the message.
 * @type string
 */
public $CharSet = 'utf8';

/**
 * The MIME Content-type of the message.
 * @type string
 */
public $ContentType = 'text/plain';

/**
 * The message encoding.
 * Options: "8bit", "7bit", "binary", "base64", and "quoted-printable".
 * @type string
 */
public $Encoding = '8bit';

/**
 * Holds the most recent mailer error message.
 * @type string
 */
public $ErrorInfo = '';

/**
 * The From email address for the message.
 * @type string
 */
public $From = 'email@dominio.com.br';  

/**
 * The From name of the message.
 * @type string
 */
public $FromName = 'Eu';

/**
 * The Sender email (Return-Path) of the message.
 * If not empty, will be sent via -f to sendmail or as 'MAIL FROM' in smtp mode.
 * @type string
 */
public $Sender = 'email@dominio.com.br';

/**
 * The Return-Path of the message.
 * If empty, it will be set to either From or Sender.
 * @type string
 * @deprecated Email senders should never set a return-path header;
 * it's the receiver's job (RFC5321 section 4.4), so this no longer does anything.
 * @link https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.4 RFC5321 reference
 */
public $ReturnPath = '';

/**
 * The Subject of the message.
 * @type string
 */
public $Subject = '';

/**
 * An HTML or plain text message body.
 * If HTML then call isHTML(true).
 * @type string
 */
public $Body = '';

/**
 * The plain-text message body.
 * This body can be read by mail clients that do not have HTML email
 * capability such as mutt & Eudora.
 * Clients that can read HTML will view the normal Body.
 * @type string
 */
public $AltBody = '';

/**
 * An iCal message part body.
 * Only supported in simple alt or alt_inline message types
 * To generate iCal events, use the bundled extras/EasyPeasyICS.php class or iCalcreator
 * @link http://sprain.ch/blog/downloads/php-class-easypeasyics-create-ical-files-with-php/
 * @link http://kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/
 * @type string
 */
public $Ical = '';

/**
 * The complete compiled MIME message body.
 * @access protected
 * @type string
 */
protected $MIMEBody = '';

/**
 * The complete compiled MIME message headers.
 * @type string
 * @access protected
 */
protected $MIMEHeader = '';

/**
 * Extra headers that createHeader() doesn't fold in.
 * @type string
 * @access protected
 */
protected $mailHeader = '';

/**
 * Word-wrap the message body to this number of chars.
 * Set to 0 to not wrap. A useful value here is 78, for RFC2822 section 2.1.1 compliance.
 * @type integer
 */
public $WordWrap = 0;

/**
 * Which method to use to send mail.
 * Options: "mail", "sendmail", or "smtp".
 * @type string
 */
public $Mailer = 'mail';

/**
 * The path to the sendmail program.
 * @type string
 */
public $Sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

/**
 * Whether mail() uses a fully sendmail-compatible MTA.
 * One which supports sendmail's "-oi -f" options.
 * @type boolean
 */
public $UseSendmailOptions = true;

/**
 * Path to PHPMailer plugins.
 * Useful if the SMTP class is not in the PHP include path.
 * @type string
 * @deprecated Should not be needed now there is an autoloader.
 */
public $PluginDir = '';

/**
 * The email address that a reading confirmation should be sent to.
 * @type string
 */
public $ConfirmReadingTo = '';

/**
 * The hostname to use in Message-Id and Received headers
 * and as default HELO string.
 * If empty, the value returned
 * by SERVER_NAME is used or 'localhost.localdomain'.
 * @type string
 */
public $Hostname = '';

/**
 * An ID to be used in the Message-Id header.
 * If empty, a unique id will be generated.
 * @type string
 */
public $MessageID = '';

/**
 * The message Date to be used in the Date header.
 * If empty, the current date will be added.
 * @type string
 */
public $MessageDate = '';

/**
 * SMTP hosts.
 * Either a single hostname or multiple semicolon-delimited hostnames.
 * You can also specify a different port
 * for each host by using this format: [hostname:port]
 * (e.g. "smtp1.example.com:25;smtp2.example.com").
 * You can also specify encryption type, for example:
 * (e.g. "tls://smtp1.example.com:587;ssl://smtp2.example.com:465").
 * Hosts will be tried in order.
 * @type string
 */
public $Host = 'mail.meudominio.com.br';

/**
 * The default SMTP server port.
 * @type integer
 * @TODO Why is this needed when the SMTP class takes care of it?
 */
public $Port = 587;

/**
 * The SMTP HELO of the message.
 * Default is $Hostname.
 * @type string
 * @see PHPMailer::$Hostname
 */
public $Helo = '';

/**
 * What kind of encryption to use on the SMTP connection.
 * Options: '', 'ssl' or 'tls'
 * @type string
 */
public $SMTPSecure = '';

/**
 * Whether to enable TLS encryption automatically if a server supports it,
 * even if `SMTPSecure` is not set to 'tls'.
 * Be aware that in PHP >= 5.6 this requires that the server's certificates are valid.
 * @type boolean
 */
public $SMTPAutoTLS = true;
```

OBS: Tentei utilizar um outro plugin de newsletter, nele apenas coloquei meu email, nome, o SMTP coloquei como `localhost` e desabilitei o protocolo de segurança (ssl, tls) e também a autenticação por login e senha. Apenas fazendo isso funcionou! Tentei fazer o mesmo neste código mas sem sucesso, alguém poderia me ajudar??

(Por que não uso esse e largo o SendPress?? Porque o SendPress possui mais funcionalidades e não tem limite de subinscritos)

Comment: O [SPF](http://www.antispam.br/admin/spf/), no DNS, está permitindo o envio em nome do seu domínio ao IP deste servidor?

Comment: O meu SPF está direcionado ao da LocaWeb, que é o servidor contratado. Não tem faixa de ip, é só `spf.locaweb.com.br`

Comment: Na LocaWeb tem como alterar. Altera incluindo seu ip.

Comment: Então, no lugar do ip eu adicionei este caminho. Foi a recomendação que recebi da própria LocaWeb. Isso pode estar causando algum conflito?

Comment: http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Entrada_TXT

Comment: Entendo. Bom, isso é o que pode estar causando este conflito? De enviar os emails localmente mas para emails externos não??

Comment: Se não me falha a memória o PHP Mailer usa o sendmail por padrão. É esse o seu caso?

Comment: Sim, no código é mencionado o sendmail

Comment: Então, adicionando o meu IP ao SPF fará com que o mesmo esteja "liberado" para enviar emails a qualquer dominio em forma de newsletter?

Comment: [Tenta enviar com o sendmail](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Como_enviar_e-mail_via_linha_de_comando_(ou_em_Shell_Script)) sem o php para ver se o e-mal chega. Se não chegar, tem que rever a configuração do sendmail.

Comment: Na verdade o servidor de e-mails destino vai verificar que seu servidor pode enviar e-mail como se fosse seu domínio.

Comment: criei uma resposta para não transformar os comentários em chat.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você precisa especificar o [SPF](http://www.antispam.br/admin/spf/) do DNS. A locaweb indica esta alteração: [Locaweb Entrada TXT](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Entrada_TXT). O SPF diz ao servidor destino que o seu servidor pode enviar e-mails pelo domínio.

Normalmente, o PHP Mailer usa o sendmail por padrão. Se este for o caso, o melhor é você fazer um teste manual direto pelo console, isolando o problema. A LocaWeb também tem um [tutorial](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Como_enviar_e-mail_via_linha_de_comando_(ou_em_Shell_Script)) sobre isso. Se falhar, será hora de perder um tempo [reconfigurando o sendmail](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Configurando-o-SendMail).

Comment: Adicionei o meu IP ao TXT do SPF. Porém, creio que o problema seja na configuração do sendpress, pois como disse tentei utilizar um outro plugin  e o mesmo funcionou. Deixei o trecho do phpmailer onde fiz algumas configurações.